# Concatenate only filtered rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

How to `CONCATENATE` only filtered text from range D2:D7 to cell D9.

This I use for non filtered

```
=CONCATENATE(D2;D3;D4;D5;D6;D7)
```

[image: not filtered]
[image: filtered]

Comment: you want only text?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Is there also way, how to do this automaticaly, everytime I have different filter results? Example : I will have new filter results showing only rows 5:7. How to CONCATENATE only those filtered results from cells D5:D7 and not from D2:D7?

Comment: based on images you provided you are using filtered layer eg. you cant unless you use solid formula like QUERY(), VLOOKUP(), FILTER() to filter out your dataset

Comment: Can you please show me how that formula should look like? Thank you

Comment: `=QUERY(A1:C3, "select A,B,C where B < 500", 0)`

Comment: Could you please show me how to implement this, so that whenever I will filter those data from rows 2:7 it will CONCATENATE only in cells from range D2:D7 which are visible after filtering?

Comment: sure, I added 2nd answer

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ## data on Sheet1:

  > [image: 1]

---

- ## data on Sheet2:

  > [image: 2]

  - **A1:** **`=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C, "select A,B,C where B < 500", 0)`** **filter out data to Sheet2**
  - **D1:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A),
          ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(
          QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C),,COLUMNS(A1:C)),
          " ","/"))),))`** **formula to join all data per row**
  - **E1:** **`=REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("/",QUERY(QUERY(D1:D,"select *"),
         "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")),"/\d+","")`** **formula to join all data in D column**

Answer (score 0):

```
=JOIN("/";{SPLIT(D1;"0123456789/")\
           SPLIT(D2;"0123456789/")\
           SPLIT(D3;"0123456789/")})
```

[image: 1]